# Ford Ranger Overheating issue

Tags: ford, overheating, ranger

I have a 2001 Ford Ranger V6 3.0. I recently overheated during a 1 mile trip to the store so I let it sit for a while and put more coolant in. Later the next day i noticed a leak from the bottom radiator hose at the section from which id imagine is the small hose that connects to the thermostat housing. I replaced the hose and did a radiator flush as well. Today i was driving and then i heard a loud taping noise coming from the engine bay and started to lose power then it ultimately just shut off. My temps were normal and i did not see any coolant leaks or anything and luckily i was able to get home where i let it sit again. After a few hours of sitting it started right up and was running good, so I let it sit for another 30 minutes running to see if my temps changed. After about 15 minutes of idling I started to hear a hissing near the bottom of the radiator hose that connects to the block. I had noticed that i made a grave mistake and forgot to put the hose clamp back on the hose. My question is, is it possible that after running for a while enough pressure could build that could cause the hose to loosen around the bib of the engine and cause the symptoms that i have listed? Could I have made a simple mistake that lead to bigger issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Taurus with the same 3.0 engine.  Yes, without a hose clamp the lower return hose will build pressure and leak.

This mistake could indeed lead to a much bigger overheating problem.  You have introduced air into the coolant system, which becomes trapped and leads to hot spots throughout the engine that can cause real damage.

To correct this problem, you must bleed the system of air.  Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nThsFGa1vuE) for some excellent instructions!

Also, those loud taps under the hood and loss of power could be a sign that you seriously overheated the engine.  You may blow a head gasket soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could be from the pressure built up and the hose started to leak surprised it didn't blow it off the block from the pressure.. if temp gauge read fine then I would check the coolant temp sensor cuz my 04 explorer did the same thing but never said I was running hot it just shut off then vapor lockd.. I would suggest to go ahead and replace head gasket and temp sensor and thermostat and use the red high heat temp rtv gasket maker/sealant for head and thermostat housing gasket when putting them back on from removal to replace the parts.. also easy way to check to see if the head gasket is blown pull the oil dipstick and see if the oil is milky or real thing as if it's water not oil on the stick.. and if there is any smoke coming from exhaust and what color it is..